# How to reset the keyboard mapping?

Tags: macos, keyboard

After installing a system upgrade the "end" button on the external keyboard stopped working. Several months ago I had some modifications somewhere to make the home/end button function the same natural way which they work on other operating systems (like Windows). I don't remember what I did, but I need to reset all keyboard re-mapping to reconfigure the keys again.

Using Karabiner Event Viewer, I can see that the keypress is not detected at all when I press the "end" key. (the external keyboard is flawless when is connected to a Windows machine.)

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed by resetting PRAM as was explained at [MacBook keyboard and trackpad not working?](https://macpaw.com/how-to/keyboard-trackpad-not-working)

Keyboard mapping on Mac is super annoying, glad that this was fixed.